# Can't use FAXCOMEXLib in VS 2010 anymore?

Tags: com, visual-studio-2010, migration

I'm just in the process of moving from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.

One of my projects use the *Microsoft Fax Service Extended COM Type Library*. After converting the project to VS 2010 I get the following compiler error:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1558,9): error MSB3648: The Keycontainer-path "VS_KEY_812A0248FF872DEC" ist invalid. KeyContainer must point to an existing file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1558,9): warning MSB3283: Wrapperassembly for type library "FAXCOMEXLib" not found.

I tried to remove FAXCOMEXLib from the project and adding it again, but it did not help.

I got a similar problem with other COM references.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It's got a problem strong-naming the assembly because it can't find the key container.  Can't see it from here either, where is it?

Comment: I wonder what KeyContainer it needs for FaxComExLib??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug. Take a look at [this Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535912/cannot-reference-com-components-from-assembly-targeting-the-net-3-5-framework-when-signed-with-a-pfx) entry which has a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

this might not be relevant for you any more, but might be so for others. I've had the same problem recently and in my searches I found this list of common [FAXCOMEXLib](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/faxcomexlib) errors. I helped me, in any case.